# Looking for variables in two lines

Tags: perl

I have a text file that is formatted as follows:

44.820731  122 ah

44.947098  122 m

I need to find a certain last variable before another certain last variable. So for example, I want to find a set of 2 lines where the last part of one line is "ng" and the last part of the next line is "b", like the example below. I only need the lines to be put into variables and printed out where this pattern holds.

50.820731  122 ng

51.947098  122 b

My original idea was to write a regex and then assign the match variables like the code shows below:

```
    $line = m/\s+(\d\.\d+)\s(\d+)\s(.+\Z)/;
    my ($time, $number, $phone) = $1, $2, $3;
```

but then I don't know how to compare `$phone` in the sets of two lines.

Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way - I am new to perl.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the entire file read into memory, you can search multiple lines at once:

```
$file =~ m/^\s*(\d+\.\d+\s+\d+\s+ng)\n\s*(\d+\.\d+\s+\d+\s+b)/ms ;
```

Otherwise you end up writing some kind of state machine.

If the endings are going to be changing, you can even use variables for them:

```
my $end1= 'ng' ;
my $end2= 'b' ;
$file =~ m/^\s*(\d+\.\d+\s+\d+\s+$end1)\n\s*(\d+\.\d+\s+\d+\s+$end2)/ms ;
```

And if you have to deal with DOS newlines, adjust to suit:

```
$file =~ m/^\s*(\d+\.\d+\s+\d+\s+$end1)\r*\n\s*(\d+\.\d+\s+\d+\s+$end2)/ms ;
```

Comment: Note that your code allows blank lines between teh two lines. Replace `\n\s*` with `\n[^\S\n]*` to fix that.

Answer (score -1):

As always with this kind of problem, either read the entire file into memory, or keep a copy of the preceding lines you might need in memory.

```
my $prev = <>;
if (defined($prev)) {
   while (my $this = <>) {
      if ($this =~ /\sb$/ && $prev =~ /\sng$/) {
         # Do whatever you want with the two lines here.
         print($prev);
         print($this);
      }

      $prev = $this;
   }
}
```